# How to lay a button right after the ellipsis in text view?

Tags: uitextview

I have a textview which has been already truncated by this:

```
self.textView.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 2;
self.textView.textContainer.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
```

Now, I wanna lay a button right after the ellipsis, so I can expand it at my own, but I dont have any idea how to do it. Could you suggest me some solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: hey what did you end up doing, I have the same question, also if you found a way to check when the NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail is in affect that helps too thanks.